# Hide parent div when all child has specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div class="woof_container woof_container_producer">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Nike<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Reebok<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Adidas<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Puma<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="woof_container woof_container_category">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Jacket<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">T-shirt<span class="quantity">(3)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Dress<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Boots<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to hide entire `".woof_container"` when all `"li"` items inside has `".hide"` class.

So in this example `".woof_container.woof_container_producer"` should hide but `".woof_container.woof_container_category"` should be still visible.

Can You help me with that? Thx!

Comment: why do not you use a server side if statement ?

Comment: Not with [css], but [jquery] is relatively straightforward (answer already provided).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.woof_container').each(function(){

  var hide = true;
  
  $(this).find('li').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')) {
      hide =false;
    }
  });
  
  if(hide) {
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woof_container woof_container_producer">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Nike<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Reebok<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Adidas<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Puma<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="woof_container woof_container_category">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Jacket<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">T-shirt<span class="quantity">(3)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Dress<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Boots<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all li, if it has hide class then hide parent div using each loop.

```js
$('.woof_container').each(function(){
  var hasAllHide = true;
  $(this).find('li.woof_term').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('hide')){
      hasAllHide = false;
    }
  });
  if(!hasAllHide){
   $(this).css('display','none');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woof_container woof_container_producer">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Nike<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Reebok<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Adidas<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Puma<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="woof_container woof_container_category">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Jacket<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">T-shirt<span class="quantity">(3)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Dress<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Boots<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var parents = $("div.woof_container");
   parents.each(function(elem){
      if($(this).find("li.hide").length != $(this).find("li").length)
      {
          $(this).hide()
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> *What I need is to hide entire ".woof_container" when all "li" items inside has ".hide" class.*

You can

1) find the container element that have same count for element with class `woof_term` and 'hide' using filter function

2) hide elements  returned in above step.

```js
$('.woof_container ').filter(function(){
     var $this = $(this)
     return $this.find('.woof_term').length == $this.find('.woof_term.hide').length 
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="woof_container woof_container_producer">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term hide">Nike<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Reebok<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Adidas<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term hide">Puma<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="woof_container woof_container_category">
 <div class="woof_container_inner">
  <div class="woof_block_html_items">
   <ul class="woof_list">
    <li class="woof_term">Jacket<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">T-shirt<span class="quantity">(3)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">Dress<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
    <li class="woof_term">Boots<span class="quantity">(0)</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okey, I am in misread. It should be all items hide of course.

Answer (score -2):

1.use javascript
2.Do not set height property in the li‘s parents node's classes，when all li hide，the height will be 0